# How to make an if statement to stop access from running query?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, search-form

I'm using Microsoft access and I want to make an if statement that basically does:

if the search criteria are all blank, then open a message box that says "something I write" and an OK button. The ok would throw you back to the search from and not run query.

My issue is that if all of the search criteria are left blank and someone hits search, it'll crash access. So I wanna make something that'll stop someone from running the query in blank. I am using a form with 6 different criteria's called Standards, Duds, ID, Desc1, Desc2, and Excel.

Just to let everyone know too, I am pretty stupid when it comes to coding and stuff so if you could spell it out in a way a 4 year old could understand that'd be great.

I would like something that reads:

If `[Forms]![Search]![Standards]` AND `[Forms]![Search]![CADID]` is blank then

`MsgBox("You cant do this")` - and then this would send you back to the form

```
ElseIf
```

Run the query normally.

Currently my code looks a bit like:

`SELECT DISTINCT Standards.Name, Standards.[Catalog Id]`, - then a bunch of other tables and their respective columns

```
WHERE(((Standards.Name)Like"*"& [Forms]![Search]![Standards] & "*") AND ((Standards.[Catalog ID]) Like "*" & [Forms]![Search]![CADID] & "*"));
```

I dont know why it ends there. Where it reads [Standards] and [CADID] after WHERE are the text boxes a user and write in a form.let me know how much more detail you need.

Comment: where is the if condition i didn't see in your question

Comment: Would you be able to add some information to your question?  Such as any code that you are currently using.  This will help us understand your question better and allow us to provide you with some solutions.   Also, welcome to StackOverflow!  I would highly recommend reviewing the information found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask regarding how to ask questions in order to receive the best answers.  Something I wish I had read a lot earlier when I started here!

Comment: I havent really played with the code yet. All ive done is add tables to access, made a query that compares the tables and outputs matches.

whats i just want to know what the general format for is statements in access work. Like can i write
IF "Standard" is blank
then open message box saying "stuff"
end if

Comment: this comment stuff just completely destroyed the formatting to my comment....

Comment: You can just add it into the main body of your post.  Comments are very limited in formatting.

Comment: Has Access allowed you to call a field in your Standards table "Name"? Name is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your search code is, but here's a template to work with. Put this in the On-click event of the button that executes your search and make sure you add whatever code executes your search in place of the comment I've left in the else part of the `If` statement below.

```vb
If _
    (IsNull([Forms]![Search]![Standards]) Or _
    [Forms]![Search]![Standards] = "") And _
    (IsNull([Forms]![Search]![CADID]) Or _
    [Forms]![Search]![CADID]) = "" _
Then

    MsgBox "Please complete both Standards and CADID fields before searching", vbCritical Or vbOKOnly, "Search Error"

Else

    ' your search code here

End If
```

Comment: I get an error saying:
Invalid SQL Statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', "SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: The code in my answer is VBA, not SQL, so you won't be able to add it to a query. Are you using a form for your search?

Comment: yes. i have a form where you write in the inputs and then when you run the query, the query takes those inputs and matches them to the tables

Comment: How are the results of a search shown? In a subform?

Comment: It creates a table with columns of the criteria in the query and form. 
So when you run uit it comes back with
Standard  Dud CADID and a description column

Comment: I'm still confused. Does the first line of your query have the word `INTO` in there somewhere? I.e. Like this: `SELECT myField1, myField2, INTO myNewTable`?

Comment: nope. the way i made this query was I brought in three tables in access, made relationships relating each of them and then dragged and dropped the necessary fields down below to be able to have criteria. 

I then put Like"*'& [Forms]![Search]![Standards] & "*" in the criteria so that it picks up whatever is in the search form i made. When I write something in the form box and then hit search, it runs the query using what i wrote in the boxes as criteria and then the query turns into a table. I have to click on design view to re-run the query.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. That's a somewhat unusual way of using a form.. When you say you "hit search" is that a button on your form? If so can you update your question to show the code behind that button ?

Comment: Matt was your `if` statement format personal preference or was there something that made you choose to use two checks instead of `Nz([Forms]![Search]![CADID],"") = ""`?  I honestly don't know which is more efficient so that is why I am asking.

Comment: @Newd I think it's probably just superstition on my part.. and also because when answering on here I don't know exactly how someone might have there db setup :) There's a bit about Null vs Zero Length String here: https://599cd.com/tips/access/null-zls/ Your way of using `Nz` seems perfectly fine, though I suppose you are having to return a value for a null first (like "") and then test for that value, rather than just testing for the null in the first place.

Comment: Hey everyone. I just wanted to say that I figured out how to work out my issue. I didnt know that queries use sql but forms use macro and I was able to make a macro in my form that says: if the text boxes are blank show a message saying "blahblahblah".
As you could tell I really don't know much about this but still wanted to say thanks for trying to help. Ill be sure to try to make my questions more detailed in the future.

Comment: @MattHall i am using a button in my form. basically I have 6 text boxes that a user can fill out, then when they fill at least one, the person would click on the button and the query will run. Thanks for the help.